# How can I change my list into string properly?

Tags: python, string, list

my list looks like this

```
['Athens Greece Baghdad Iraq', 'Athens Greece Bangkok Thailand', 'Athens Greece Beijing China', 'Athens Greece Berlin Germany']
```

I tried to change this list into string through this code.

```
def conver_list(org_list, seperator = ''):
    return seperator.join(org_list)
```

But the problem is the result looks like

```
'Athens Greece Baghdad IraqAthens Greece Bangkok ThailandAthens Greece Beijing ChinaAthens Greece Berlin Germany'
```

How can I change the result like this

```
 'Athens Greece Baghdad Iraq Athens Greece Bangkok Thailand Athens Greece Beijing China Athens Greece Berlin Germany'
```

Comment: Set the separator equal to ```' ' ``` instead of ```''```

Comment: Why do you join with an empty string if you want to join with a space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
def conver_list(org_list, seperator = ' '):
    return seperator.join(org_list)
```

Just replace the `''` with `' '`. (add a space between the inverted colons)